# Facebook style fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

On my site, http://www.merkato.hu, the header has a fixed position. On desktop browsers, this works well - but on mobile devices, zooming the page makes the header unusable due to the fixed positioning.

I have tried a method for making the height and html absolute positioned to header and content, and overflow set to scroll - but there are scripts which need the body to be scrollable.

What is the best way to accomplish a fixed-header for mobile? None of what I'm finding seems worthwhile for iDevices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem. Support for `fixed` positioning is broken or missing in most mobile devices. First mobile browsers that support that came with devices produced this year, or so.

I remember that [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) team struggled with fixed headers and footers for quite a while.

They got it working, so I recommend either using jQuery Mobile (or some other framework that can do that obviously) or digging into their JS and CSS to find out how that works.

Anyway, without about 20 different test devices you won't be able to be sure it works. So unless you have a respectable budget, you have to stick to the well-tested open-source solutions.